# JFrames running on EDT or not?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I have a multi JFrame app (JFrames designed by Netbeans GUI design) and would like to understand if I properly initialize each one on the EDT ?
My initial JFrame is a simple and small login frame used for..logins. I initialize it like this :

```
 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new LoginFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
 });
```

Upon successful login, from the LoginFrame class I start my main JFrame and dispose the LoginFrame :

```
dispose();
new MyMainFrame();
```

Then MyMainFrame's constructor calls the `initComponets()` method and does all the initialization.

So my question is, does MyMainFrame (and any subsequent JFrames initialized in the same way as MyMainFrame) run on the EDT ? Are there any better ways to do this ?

Many thanks

Comment: System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()) ?

Comment: `Current Thread : AWT-EventQueue-0` Is that the EDT ?

Comment: Yes this is it.

Comment: *"I have a multi JFrame app"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the link, I indeed checked that post before posting this question and it is not related to my question. I am not interested on opinions on whether it's a good or bad practice to use multiple JFrames

Comment: *"I am not interested on opinions"* Oh, it's more than that. It's a warning that most people who can help, will be unwilling to waste time on any problems that crop up with apps. that have multiple frames. And they will. All the best with it!  

Comment: @Andrew I did not just say _"I am not interested on opinions"_ , I said _"I am not interested on opinions on whether it's a good or bad practice to use multiple JFrames"_ . As per my question I think it's obvious that I have already decided to use multiple JFrames and I am trying to find the best way to do it.

Comment: @Andrew and even if it is indeed a bad practice, is StackOverflow really meant to be used for question posts by people who only apply the best practices in each case ??

Comment: `As per my question I think it's obvious that I have already decided to use multiple JFrames ` - no it is not obvious to us. We don't know what other option you may have considered. We don't know your knowledge level so we are providing advice on the better way to design an application. The fact that you need to ask a basic question like this imples you are probably designing the app this way because you don't know any better. You should be grateful someone took the time to suggest a better approach. `Are there any better ways to do this ?` - and by the way you did ask for an opinion.`

Comment: @camickr As per the post provided by Andrew, I am not at all convinced that my approach is REALLY a bad practice as the opinions on using multiple Frames in a Swing app vary a lot. It also depends on the context and the requirements of the app. I've taken the time to study that post and decided to go for multi Frame approach (2 Frames..) as I thought it was the best approach for my requirements. I indeed ask a basic question but apparently all you experienced devs spent more time trying to force your subjective opinion, rather than providing an answer to a "basic" question

Comment: Again, we have no idea that may have read that link in the past and decided to use a different approach. Andrew took the time to make a suggestion as per your statement "asking for a better way...". You then responded you were not interested in an opinion contradicting the above statement. The suggestion to NOT use a separate frame was a reasonable suggestion based on the overall question.

Comment: Ok then I believe I was misunderstood and apologies for this. By asking whether there are better ways to do this I didn't really mean moving away from the multi Frame approach. I was asking for suggestions on better approaches within the multi Frame context.